# Handling MongoDB's asynchronous function in Node.js POST request before response.end();

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Yesterday, I made 3 unsuccessful tries to achieve this and even ended up asking, but the code I showed brought even more confusion since it was just a part of the request, so nobody could tell if there is more after it or not and how all of this even works.

Today, I'm willing to fix this mistake of mine and I can't deny that I still need help.

```
// Sign Up
app.post("/join/", function(request, response) {
    var result = []; // An array that stores strings that indicate whether or not the user should give a different input in the fields.

    // Getting the input (not everything is included to make it as minimal as possible)
    var firstname = request.body.firstname;
    // ...
    var email = request.body.email;
    var password = request.body.password;
    // ...

    // An example of storing a string in the array when something is wrong.
    if (firstname.length > 255) {
        result.push("firstname-long");
    }
    else {
        if (firstname.length === 0) {
            result.push("firstname-enter");
        }
    }
    // For instance, if the array contains "firstname-enter", the response.end() function will send it back to the Ajax request and based on what it contains, it's going to mark the input fields red and output reasons why.

    // ...

    // Validating the e-mail
    if (!validator.validate(email)) {
        result.push("email-enter");
    }
    else {
        if (email.length > 255) {
            result.push("email-long");
        }
        else {
            // This is the part that I'm stuck with. I want to check whether the e-mail is taken or not.
            async function emailValidate(email) {
                const db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
                const dbo = db.db("nemalp");
                const data = await dbo.collection("ids").find({ email: email }).toArray().catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        return null;
                });
                    return data;
            }
            
            emailValidate(email).then((data) => {
                if (data && data.length > 0) {
                    result.push('email-taken');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // There are more checks after that... for example:

    // ...

    if (!regex.test(String(password))) {
        result.push("password-enter");
    }
    else {
        if (/\s/.test(String(password))) {
            result.push("password-spaces");
        }
        else {
            if (password.length > 128) {
                result.push("password-long");
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    // It's time to send back the results.
    response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

It may be a long snippet, considering the fact that I'm supposed to be as minimal as possible but nobody could understand what I am doing.

So, as you can see, there is an asynchronous function down below. It checks if another user is already using the entered e-mail. And if that's true, an `"email-taken"` string should be pushed into the `result` variable. I've tried outputting it to the console and it technically works but it seems like `response.end()` is faster than it, so if the e-mail is actually taken, the user would never know. I was told to use `async` and `await` functions and I've tried but I don't even think I understand how they work... yet...

So far, my head came up with an alternative solution - make another array, then push some values that indicate if those asynchronous functions are complete and use a `while()` statement to check if they indeed are, before using `response.end()`. I have no idea how safe this is though...

Comment: `result.push('email-taken')` will be executed after `response.end(JSON.stringify(result))`. You should either await `emailValidate(email)` or move the code into `then`

Comment: I see! Thank you for pointing that out, since I wasn't even sure what's going on. What can I do to make it execute before it?

Comment: You should either await `emailValidate(email)` or move the code into `then`

Comment: Okay, I tried that but I got an error: `await is only valid in async function` when I replaced the `async` keyword with the `await` one.

Comment: You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. You can't develop complex projects by trial and error.

Comment: Fine, good. I still don't understand a thing. Why are we exactly waiting 2 seconds for this? What if it doesn't happen during these two seconds? And in the end, aren't we still performing an asynchronous function? How is `response.end()` going to wait for it?

Comment: `MongoClient.connect` returns a promise. You can either await it or subscribe with `then`. The same for `dbo.collection("ids").find`. `emailValidate(email)` is async function that returns a promise. You are subscribing with `then`.

Comment: Okay but... isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: No, `response.end` is not in the `then` block.